# Matrix Multiplication in VBA and storing values in another matrix

Tags: arrays, vba, matrix

I stuck with pure matrix multiplication. I have two matrix: ArrW and ArrC. Each of them consists of 4 elements. The results should be saved in a third matrix, in the first slot: ArrWs(1). Afterwards I change the numbers in the ArrW and multiply this matrix with the same ArrC. The results should be stored in ArrWd(2).

During debugging the line `ArrWs(x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(ArrC, ArrW)` causes error. I do not know why. I checked the fulfilment of both matrix ArrW and ArrC. Each of them has 4 numbers- as planned.

```
Sub Matrix()

Dim TabelaEK As Range
Dim Size As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim ArrW As Variant
Dim ArrWs As Variant
Dim ArrC As Variant

Set TabelaEK = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ek").Range.Cells(1, 1)
Size = Range("E2").Value

ReDim ArrW(1 To Size)
ReDim ArrC(1 To Size)
ReDim ArrWs(1 To Size)

For x = 1 To Size 'Size is 4
    ArrW(x) = Cells(TabelaEK.Row + x, TabelaEK.Column + Size + 1)
Next
        'MsgBox ArrW(1)
        'MsgBox ArrW(2)
        'MsgBox ArrW(3)
        'MsgBox ArrW(4)

For x = 1 To Size
    For y = 1 To Size
        ArrC(y) = Cells(TabelaEK.Row + x, TabelaEK.Column - 1 + y)
    Next
        'MsgBox ArrC(1)
        'MsgBox ArrC(2)
        'MsgBox ArrC(3)
        'MsgBox ArrC(4)

    ArrWs(x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(ArrC, ArrW) 'here is the error!

Next
    'MsgBox ArrWs(1)
    'MsgBox ArrWs(2)
    'MsgBox ArrWs(3)
    'MsgBox ArrWs(4)
End Sub
```

Comment: MMULT ( and most of the arrays in Excel functions) consume and return 2 dimensional arrays.  You are providing one dimensional arrays, hence the error.

Comment: I cannot agree. MMULT with two 1-dimensional arrays works pretty well in Excel sheet. In the Microsoft help, there is also any restriction in terms of the size of the matrix.

Comment: that was just cute.

Comment: Hi there. A number of folks in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they worry about people feeling excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MMULT requires the number of columns in array1 to match the number of rows in array2. So with one dimensional array you are saying `1 = UBound(ArrW)`
If there is more than one row then it should fail.

[MMULT](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/mmult-function-40593ed7-a3cd-4b6b-b9a3-e4ad3c7245eb)

> The number of columns in Array1 must be the same as the number of rows
>   in Array2, and both arrays must contain only numbers.